# CP1256 Converts Persian YEH to Arabic YEH

Tags: php, unicode, character-encoding

CP1256 unicode table in php converts Persian character YEH (**ی**) to Arabic YEH (**ي**) with following code:

```
$str = iconv("CP1256", "UTF-8", $str);
```

I don't know if it has any other issues with other characters, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a thing as Persian YEH in CP1256. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1256. This is an Arabic encoding for windows. The best way is to convert the ARABIC character to Persian after conversion.

Comment: Your suggested way won't work on strings those have both arabic and persian words.

Answer (score 0):

Try reporting it to PHP bug tracker.

Comment: Please explain, I don’t understand what you mean by Persian character YEH (ی) in the context of a string to be treated as CP1256 encoded. That encoding has no representation for ARABIC LETTER FARSI YEH (U+06CC). And if I test in the opposite direction, iconv("UTF-8", "CP1256", "testing ی character"), I get “testing ” and error indicator is set, i.e. `iconv` does not treat “ی” as representable in CP1256.